# maven-gae-plugin 0.9.2 is deploying with google app engine 1.5.2, but should be 1.6.1

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, maven, maven-gae-plugin

mvn gae:deploy gave us the following "info":

[INFO]

[INFO] <<< maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:deploy (default-cli) @ gk <<<

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:deploy (default-cli) @ gk ---

[INFO] Updating Google App Engine Server...

---

### There is a new version of the SDK available.

Latest SDK:
Release: 1.6.1
Timestamp: Wed Nov 09 16:16:16 EST 2011
API versions: [1.0]

---

Your SDK:
Release: 1.5.2
Timestamp: Mon Jul 18 19:48:56 EDT 2011
API versions: [1.0]

But we have gae version 1.6.1 in my pom.xml file:

```
<gae.version>1.6.1</gae.version>
```

And we're sure the code is compiled with 1.6.1.

How do we make sure 1.6.1 is used to deploy?

( apologize for the format :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the version:

```
        <properties>
            <gae.version>1.6.1</gae.version>
        </properties>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>${gae.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The `unpack` goal gives maven ability to download GAE SDK and store it in local maven repo (/.m2). Use it with `mvn gae:unpack`